# how to export key pair to ssh EC2 from another system

Tags: amazon-ec2

Me and my friend are working on AWS EC2 first time and using their free tier plan for 1st year.

Both of us have MAC and my friend has created EC2 instance & key pair.

My query is how can I export that key pair to my local machine as I need to do SSH to EC2 instance.

Or do I need to create new key pair ?

Comment: is it windows or linux ec2 or windows ec2?

Comment: Have you downloaded the private key?

Comment: t2.micro, private key is on friend's Mac. I would like to SSH as well, what's the best practice to follow ?

Comment: You don't have any option you need to copy the private key from your friend. You can't download the private key again